# Intel Dual BandWireless-AC 3168 does not work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

I am unable to connect to wifi - the option of wireless connectivity is not shown; there is the only the option of ethernet.
I am using Ubuntu version 16.04.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Intel Dual BandWireless-AC 3168 802.11 ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.0 Combo Adapter
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110] 

$ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
$ modprobe iwl3945
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwl3945': Operation not permitted
$ ifconfig wlan0 up
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

[image: the screen shot of the problem wifi option is not there top right corner]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: #lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
 DeviceName: Intel Dual BandWireless-AC 3168 802.11 ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.0 Combo Adapter
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]

Comment: The command you are looking for is: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`

Comment: @chili555 `iwlwifi` does not support the device on the 4.4 kernel.

Comment: @AmbujDhakad Please also add output of `uname -a; dmesg | grep iwl`.

Comment: The 4.8 kernel did not install for some reason. I did not check the PPA yet. Anyway you need the 4.8 kernel to get the wireless work.

Answer (score 1):

This adapter is supported since kernel 4.6.

The kernel version in Ubuntu 16.04 is 4.4.

You can install kernel 4.8 to Ubuntu 16.04 this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-generic-lts-yakkety
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa
```

Reboot after you do it.

After the `linux-generic-lts-yakkety` package appears in main Ubuntu repositories (it should happen soon) it will start getting updates.

You also need to install firmware this can be done by

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.161_all.deb
```

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa
sudo: unable to resolve host ambuj-pc
 This ppa is used for building pre-release and test kernels.

It IS NOT RECOMMENDED that you subscribe to this PPA.

 More info: https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel removing it

Comment: So press Enter. The PPA will be removed by the last command.

Comment: it didn't worked after the booting , problem is still same.i followed the process

Comment: You need the firmware. Install it and reboot again.

Comment: It works for me. Just run the command. Do not type it. Copy and paste it to the terminal.

Comment: everything done still problem remains same

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` again TO YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: it is working now,  thanks for your help @Pilot6

Comment: As of 2017-09-17, the linux-generic-lts-yakkety package is gone, but this answer helped me: https://askubuntu.com/a/907894/324965