# Intel Dual BandWireless-AC 3168 driver PPA doesn't exist

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel

Hi I have exactly same problem as 
[Intel Dual BandWireless-AC 3168 does not work on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847971/intel-dual-bandwireless-ac-3168-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-16-04)

I am new and I dont have 50 reputaion to comment on the question.

When I run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa
```

it shows

```
ERROR: '~canonical-kernel-team' user or team does not exist.
Error: 'ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa' invalid
```

I am connected to the internet already. Is there another way to get kernel 4.8?

Comment: If you're looking to install a new kernel to solve your wireless problem, why don't you just update to 16.10 where it's already supported?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try manually adding the repo instead?

```
sudo echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-kernel-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-kernel-team/ppa/ubuntu xenial main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

*NB. Be wary, as this is a PPA containing pre-release; unstable and testing kernels.  These could potentially disable or break your system.*