# How to get Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168 to work on Ubuntu 14.04.5?

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, hp, intel-wireless

I searched many solutions on this site but most of them were referring to Broadcom Wifi drivers while mine has Intel one.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
arijit-01:51,Wed Feb 08:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
```

Output of `rfkill list`

```
arijit-01:54,Wed Feb 08:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

Output of `uname -a; dmesg | grep iwl`

```
arijit-01:55,Wed Feb 08:~$ uname -a; dmesg | grep iwl
Linux HP-AU134TX 4.4.0-62-generic #83~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 18:10:30 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Pls help

Comment: You need the 4.8 kernel. There is an answer for 16.04. In 16.10 it just works.

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/847971/intel-dual-bandwireless-ac-3168-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-16-04/847982#847982