# Enabling Wifi Connection on Ubuntu 14.04 for Intel Dual Band Wireless-Ac 3168

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers

I've searched and searched for an answer to get wifi on my new-ish laptop. I came across this question which is already asked: [How to get Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168 to work on Ubuntu 14.04.5?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880938/how-to-get-intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-3168-to-work-on-ubuntu-14-04-5)
where the only answer is to upgrade to 16.04 or 16.10. Unfortunately, I am restricted to using 14.04 since I am currently trying to use ROS Indigo for a class which is only supported in Saucy (13.10) and Trusty (14.04). While it may be possible to run ROS via 16.04, as a new user I'd like to be able to follow these tutorials for ROS on 14.04 without any hiccups.

So..  Is there any way to get wifi for Trusty with this adapter?

Thank you!

Comment: please run `uname -r` and post the result.

Comment: Not the first time such question appears. I wonder why people insist on using outdated software. There are newer ROS versions that work on newer Ubuntu releases and Indigo has expected problems even in 14.04.2 or newer. So no, there's no solution because you're in a **catch 22** situation. The support for your WiFi started in kernel 4.6 and although it's possible to install such kernel or newer (preferably) in 14.04, that alone will break compatibility with "Indigo". Bottom line: Your class should be using the current ROS release instead of the outdated Indigo.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to post the kernel version:
after running uname -r
'4.4.0-63-generic'