# HP Pavilion Ubuntu 14.04 wifi not working

Tags: 14.04, wireless, hp

I have installed ubuntu in my new HP Pavilion. Wifi is not working here. Following are the outputs to help me suggest what to do:

lspci

```
05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fb (rev 10)
```

iwconfig:

```
usb0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless
```

My output for lshw is:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   version: 10
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:b4000000-b4001fff
```

(The other two blocks are ethernet details)

I request some help to help me turn on my wifi.

For further help, following is the pastebin with all the necessary details:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24373716/

Thank you for helping me out.

P.S.: My wifi is working fine with the dual booted windows 10

Comment: You are running kernel version 4.2.0-xx. This device isn't supported until kernel version 4.6. Please check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/847971/intel-dual-bandwireless-ac-3168-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-16-04/847982#847982

Comment: So, what should I do? The link says the solution for Ubuntu 16 LTS....Shall I go for Ubuntu 16 and follow it, or shall the sme work with Ubuntu 14? btw....Thanks a lot!!

Comment: P.S.: Out of curiosity, how did you know that this version wis supported 4.6.XX upwards. This is just for learning how to troubleshoot

Comment: I know of no current, reliable way to install a 4.6+ kernel in 14.04 aside from this: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ If you'd like for me to write a step-by-step, I'll be happy to do so. Alternatively, you could simply install Ubuntu 16.10. As for how I know, I have worked with wireless, especially Intel, on Ubuntu since 2005 and have seen many things come and go. You can always check to see if a device is supported by checking the driver: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 24FB` where 24FB is the pci.id of your exact device. In 14.04, it comes back empty.

Comment: In my 4.9.0-xx kernel, it reports, among others: `alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FBsv*sd00002110bc*sc*i*` Therefore, the driver will grab the device, look for firmware and get to work!

Comment: Thanks a lot!!  Got your points..... Learning is fun...I was thinking Unassigned Class was the hardware referring to WIfi Card (Realtek Made), but after your comment, I understood its the Inter made Network Controller (24FB). Thanks a lot. Hope to upgrade to Ubuntu 16 (which I thought I eventually would) and then the Kernel.

Comment: Please have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593848/254422