# No Wifi, HP Pavillion 15 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, hp

There likely is an answer for this out there, but unfortunately I have tried for 3-4 hours and cannot get any common solution to work. I am in a situation where I need to run Ubuntu 14.04, and cannot upgrade, but cannot get wifi to work with my laptop. I had initially used Ubuntu 16.04 but was forced to downgrade as I could not get an old version of PHP (5.5.9) to work correctly with Apache2.

$  lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb]               (rev 10)    
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
```

$ lshw -C network

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 15
       serial: 48:ba:4e:41:d4:57
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet         physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.21 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:130 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b4104000-b4104fff memory:b4100000-b4103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   version: 10
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:b4000000-b4001fff
```

and the wireless-info script [that is available here](https://pastebin.com/ib0X4FcN)

Most solutions to fix this involve updating the kernel. The kernel I am currently running, gotten from:

$ uname -r

```
4.8.17-040817-generic
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you for your time.

[edit]

$ rfkill list all

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had thought that Abdulla Nilam's solution had worked initially but it seems that it didn't necessarily, as after freshly installing, it did not work.

What ultimately worked was following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847971/intel-dual-bandwireless-ac-3168-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-16-04/847982#847982), but replacing yakkety with xenial.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-generic-lts-xenial
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa
```

Reboot

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux/firmware_1.161_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.161_all.deb
```

It is possible that part of Abdulla's answer did work however, because I rebooted after trying the above commands, had no change, and after following Abdulla's answer it did work... Of course I did the exact same on this install thinking it would work, so I have no way to tell what went on.