# Embedded WLAN not working on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, intel-wireless, motherboard

I am using an [AsRock x370 Taichi](http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/X370%20Taichi/#Specification) motherboard, and Ubuntu doesn't seem to be able to detect the embedded 802.11 module. It looks like it is able, however, to use the bluetooth module. The WLAN module's manufacturer is Intel.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; uname -a` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Another lead is that the wifi adapter may default to the off state as shipped.  The ASRock X299 "off" and can be set to on in the bios under

```
Advanced >> Chipset >> WLAN (Change "Default" to "Enabled")
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

For those that stumble upon this question with the same issue. I was able to solve this with the command given in [cheche's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/907894/22949) to [How do I get an Intel Wireless 3168 802.11ac wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/827795/how-do-i-get-an-intel-wireless-3168-802-11ac-wireless-card-to-work)

Specifically:

```
apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```