# Cannot connect to WiFi and Ethernet on Acer Aspire 3 A315-51-35LM with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, ethernet, acer

Laptop came with Endless OS (Linux) and everything was working fine. Formatted the hard disk and installed Windows 10 and everything is fine. Installed Ubuntu as dual boot but can't connect with neither wifi nor ethernet. Have to use tethering via phone to have internet. Without it, laptop says ethernet network disconnected even though it is still plugged in and I can't find the wireless.

Ran this

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info
```

and here's the output

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 02 Jan 2018 13:02 +08 +0800

Booted last: 02 Jan 2018 00:00 +08 +0800

Script from: 05 Dec 2017 03:13 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-104-generic #127-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 11 12:16:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:1191]
    Kernel driver in use: r8168

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
    Kernel modules: wl

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b5e0 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 17ef:7896 Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6447104  0
acer_wmi               20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 acer_wmi
cfg80211              565248  1 wl
wmi                    20480  1 acer_wmi
video                  40960  2 i915_bpo,acer_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp0s20f0u3 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp0s20f0u3' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.42.225  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::69f0:d0e1:73cf:76f8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1112 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:1
          TX packets:1358 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:480738 (480.7 KB)  TX bytes:267356 (267.3 KB)

enp2s0f1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp2s0f1' [IF2]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:126 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:19956 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19956 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:1594529 (1.5 MB)  TX bytes:1594529 (1.5 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s20f0u3  no wireless extensions.

enp2s0f1  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s20f0u3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s20f0u3
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s20f0u3

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       962     1  0 12:44 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s20f0u3
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         MediaTek
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Lenovo
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 22-Aug-2005
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s20f0u3' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/net/enp0s20f0u3
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp0s20f0u3
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 3
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       730fcc00-b3b9-3f12-9a35-d43f57f26f6a
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   730fcc00-b3b9-3f12-9a35-d43f57f26f6a | Wired connection 3
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.42.225/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.42.129
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.42.225
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.42.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 3150
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 1800
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       expiry = 1514872608
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       host_name = GAMSARUK
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.42.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       vendor_encapsulated_options = ANDROID_METERED
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::69f0:d0e1:73cf:76f8/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0f1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8168
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 8.045.08-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp2s0f1' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.1/net/enp2s0f1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Manila (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp0s20f0u3  no frequency information.

enp2s0f1  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s20f0u3  Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp2s0f1  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-104-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     E179A1F6EAA13B7BC9AF7C6
depends:        cfg80211
vermagic:       4.4.0-104-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-104-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D2A8E57424453F0D1BE1DBE
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-104-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf]
alias   pci:v00001186d00004300sv00001186sd00004B10bc*sc*i*  r8168
alias   pci:v000010ECd00008168sv*sd*bc*sc*i*            r8168

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   15.891409] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-22.50.19.14.f.bseq
[   16.048332] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[   17.162023] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   29.529864] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0f1: link is not ready
[   29.530054] enp2s0f1: 0xffffc90000692000, <MAC 'enp2s0f1' [IF2]>, IRQ 126
[   29.583689] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0f1: link is not ready
[  756.518852] rndis_host 1-3:1.0 enp0s20f0u3: renamed from usb0
[  756.556404] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20f0u3: link is not ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

(http://paste.ubuntu.com/26304429/)

But I don't know how to go on from here.
I already tried looking in other threads but didn't find a fix for the problem
I'm really sorry,but I'm new to asking questions here

## edit:

output from  `lspci | grep Network`

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fb (rev 10)
```

Comment: can you post the output of `lspci | grep Network`

Comment: @KuntalMajumder edited the post with the output

Comment: Go through the answers https://askubuntu.com/questions/827795/how-do-i-get-an-intel-wireless-3168-802-11ac-wireless-card-to-work

Comment: Ok will do thanks... I'll notify you later what happens

Comment: My wireless is now working! Thanks bruh! I didn't come across that thread before. It didn't fix my wired ethernet though but still, thank you @KuntalMajumder

Comment: I am not sure why your ethernet is working or not, cause I do have the same Ethernet controller and it doesn't need any special attention to make it work.